# Bokeh showing empty diagramm

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, pandas-bokeh

Hey guys so I have the problem that when I try to run my Code that my created diagram is empty. So I dont see my temperature and my time date.

If it helps here is my database: `id  hum  temp     time          date

                           1   59    18     10:03:06    2020-05-16

                           2   59    19     10:05:22    2020-05-16`

And here ist my Code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import sqlite3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource


output_file("test.html")

con = sqlite3.connect("/home/pi/test2.db")
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from data4 limit 10;",con)

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

p = figure()
p.line(x="time", y="temp", source = source)
show(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you not getting an error? because it looks like you did not import `pandas` at all..

Comment: I import Pandas but the diagram is still empty:(